# SQL Query - How to get paired rows by checking current row with all rows

Tags: sql-server

I have table like this :

```
ID  | Type | From | To
-----------------------
100 | A    | 10   | 14
100 | A    | 16   | 18
100 | B    | 12   | 14
100 | B    | 11   | 13
100 | B    | 17   | 18
120 | A    | 5    | 10
120 | A    | 12   | 14
120 | A    | 18   | 20
120 | A    | 18   | 20
120 | A    | 22   | 24
120 | B    | 30   | 32
120 | B    | 19   | 20
120 | B    | 10   | 14
```

My goals is to create Status column that can identify which Type B is in range of Type A Group By ID. So, my expected result is like this :

```
ID  | Type | From | To | Status
-------------------------------
100 | A    | 10   | 14 | -
100 | A    | 16   | 18 | -
100 | B    | 12   | 14 | IN
100 | B    | 11   | 13 | OUT      -> I will explain this below *)
100 | B    | 17   | 18 | IN
120 | A    | 5    | 10 | -
120 | A    | 12   | 14 | -
120 | A    | 18   | 20 | -
120 | A    | 18   | 20 | -
120 | A    | 22   | 24 | -
120 | B    | 30   | 32 | OUT
120 | B    | 19   | 20 | IN
120 | B    | 10   | 14 | OUT
```

*) Although Type B (11 - 13) is in range of Type A (10 - 14), the status will return "OUT" because Type A (10 - 14) already paired with Type B (12 - 14). Type B and Type A only have one-to-one pair which have matched range.

Actually, I already solve this problem by using CURSOR. I have to loop every row data and search for matched pair, if found, then I put flag on it.

But, I really curious whether this case can be solved by using a simpler query, because I have ten of thousands of this row data. Anyone have other idea about how to improve the query ?

Comment: At the very least you will need some kind of row numbering column, so that the *data* holds an idea of order for the `A` slots and the `B` items that want to go in them.

Comment: How do you order your rows? How did `100 | B    | 12   | 14 |` came first than `100 | B    | 11   | 13 |`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you close. To get the output you specify, you kind of need a row identity as AakashM suggests. However, if you don't care about order, and you are happy for, say, (11 - 13) to be matched and (12 - 14) not (so long as only one of them matches) then you can lose the identity and change the ORDER BY clause in the ROW_NUMBER() line to whatever tie breaker you want to use (e.g. you could use #t.[From] desc to get the same result)

```
CREATE TABLE #t 
(
    [Identity] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    [ID] INT,
    [Type] CHAR(1),
    [From] INT,
    [To] INT
);

INSERT INTO #t 
VALUES 
(100 , 'A'    , 10   , 14),
(100 , 'A'    , 16   , 18),
(100 , 'B'    , 12   , 14),
(100 , 'B'    , 11   , 13),
(100 , 'B'    , 17   , 18),
(120 , 'A'    , 5    , 10),
(120 , 'A'    , 12   , 14),
(120 , 'A'    , 18   , 20),
(120 , 'A'    , 18   , 20),
(120 , 'A'    , 22   , 24),
(120 , 'B'    , 30   , 32),
(120 , 'B'    , 19   , 20),
(120 , 'B'    , 10   , 14);

WITH a AS 
(
    SELECT ID,
           Type,
           [From],
           [To]
    FROM #t
    WHERE [Type] = 'A'
),
b AS 
(
    SELECT #t.ID,
           #t.Type,
           #t.[From],
           #t.[To], 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY #t.ID, a.[From] ORDER BY #t.[Identity]) AS rn
    FROM #t
    INNER JOIN a ON #t.ID = a.ID 
        AND #t.Type = 'B'
        AND #t.[From] >= a.[From]
        AND #t.[To] <= a.[To]
)
SELECT 
       #t.ID,
       #t.Type,
       #t.[From],
       #t.[To], 
    CASE WHEN [#t].[Type] = 'A' THEN NULL
         WHEN rn = 1 THEN 'IN'
         ELSE 'OUT'
    END              
FROM #t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT MIN(rn) AS rn 
    FROM b
    WHERE b.ID = #t.ID 
    AND b.[From] = #t.[From]
    AND b.[To] = #t.[To] ) b
```

Okay version 2 which handles multiple overlapping A and B records and matches as many pairs as it can, using From on the B record as the tiebreaker to decide which ones get matched. Note that this version definitely needs an IDENTITY column on the table so we can identity individual rows.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t
CREATE TABLE #t 
(
    [Identity] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    [ID] INT,
    [Type] CHAR(1),
    [From] DECIMAL(16,4),
    [To] DECIMAL(16,4)
);

INSERT INTO #t 
VALUES 
(100 , 'A'    , 10   , 14),
(100 , 'A'    , 16   , 18),
(100 , 'B'    , 12   , 14),
(100 , 'B'    , 11   , 13),
(100 , 'B'    , 17   , 18),
(120 , 'A'    , 5    , 10),
(120 , 'A'    , 12   , 14),
(120 , 'A'    , 18   , 20),
(120 , 'A'    , 18   , 20),
(120 , 'A'    , 22   , 24),
(120 , 'B'    , 30   , 32),
(120 , 'B'    , 19   , 20),
(120 , 'B'    , 10   , 14),
(130, 'A', 34.3050, 35.6950),
(130, 'A', 34.3050, 35.6950),
(130, 'A', 34.3050, 35.6950),
(130, 'A', 33.9650, 36.0350),
-- I removed these to see what happens when there are not enough around 
-- so only 4 of these 130Bs should match 
-- if you uncomment, all the 130 Bs will be IN
--(130, 'A', 33.9650, 36.0350),
--(130, 'A', 33.9650, 36.0350),
(130, 'B', 34.7200, 35.2800),
(130, 'B', 34.7200, 35.2800),
(130, 'B', 34.7750, 35.2250),
(130, 'B', 34.7750, 35.2250),
(130, 'B', 34.7750, 35.2250);

-- get all matches (i.e where b range is inside a range)
WITH matches AS 
(
    SELECT a.[Identity] aIdentity,
        b.[Identity] bIdentity,
        b.[From] bFrom -- carry this forward so we can order by it
    FROM #t a
    INNER JOIN #t b ON a.ID = b.ID 
        AND a.[From] <= b.[From]
        AND a.[To] >= b.[To]    
    WHERE a.[Type] = 'A'
        AND b.[Type] = 'B'
),
-- count how many matches we have for each 
counts AS 
(
    SELECT m.bIdentity,
        m.bFrom,
        COUNT(*) AS cnt,
        MIN(m.aIdentity) AS aIdentity
    FROM matches m
    GROUP BY m.bIdentity,
        m.bFrom
),
-- number the matches; where the row number here is more than the count, we are out of matches 
-- so these will show as OUT. Note the ORDER BY using the bFrom so this is what is used to prioritise
-- in the case there are not enough to go around
numbered AS
(
    SELECT c.bIdentity,
        c.bFrom,
        c.cnt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY aIdentity ORDER BY c.bFrom) rn
    FROM counts c
)
SELECT 
       #t.ID,
       #t.Type,
       #t.[From],
       #t.[To], 
    CASE WHEN [#t].[Type] = 'A' THEN NULL
         WHEN c.rn <= c.cnt THEN 'IN'
         ELSE 'OUT'
    END              
FROM #t
LEFT OUTER JOIN numbered c ON #t.[Identity] = c.bIdentity
```

Comment: wow, it really can be done just by a simple query.. but, i really don't understand why column `rn` return 2 in Type B (11 - 13) ? can you explain it ? and, if the order is important, what do i need to make it works ? i really don't get it..

Comment: If you look at my table definition, I have an IDENTITY(1,1) column, so when I insert the rows they get numbered. I then use the identity column as the ORDER BY when I do the numbering of rows that meet the criteria, so the (12-14) row which was inserted first comes first and gets 1, the (11-13) comes second and gets 2. Its really up to you if that is the correct logic. You might want to e.g. prefer the lower "from" number to be matched, in which case change the ORDER BY clause in the ROW_NUMBER() line to be the "From"

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2a4b5397a6762193cb1b59b8fe587993

can you take a look ID 130 ? why that case happen ?

Comment: Hmm its not handling multiple overlapping As and Bs and pairing them. I'll have to have a think about that, its going to be trickier. I think it is still doable though

Comment: Okay try the new version out. By the way, don't feel bad about not understanding this right away, this is some pretty complex stuff that takes practice to get good at. I've added some comments to hopefully show how i thought it through. One useful exercise for you would be to select out the content of each CTE to see how its working

Comment: i do feel very bad about not understanding it, thank you for encouraging me.. :) and many many thanks for your answers, the performance of the query has improved a lot, about 9-10 min to seconds. i'm trying to learn this query, will ask again if I don't understand.. hope u don't mind..

Comment: Hi James, i found another problem when matched range is behind the outmatch. Can you take a look at this ? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a327992d507673f9840a6dcf63a4ac69

One of the three last row data should be "IN", but because the unique key already more than count matches, it display as "OUT". I don't have idea how to fix this, can you help me ?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b3852b8bd5be9e939e0e4d04430c399b I think I reached the limit of my ability to do it in one step. This version uses a loop but should still be much faster than cursoring through the rows. It also requires an extra column to keep track of what is matched.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. tbh, it's my first time to see syntax like "OUTPUT Inserted" or "@@ROWCOUNT". I need to google it after read your answer.. :) you really taught me a lot..